# Software Update not showing 16.04.4 update

Tags: 16.04

As you can see the latest LTS 16.04.4 is out https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. I am on 16.04.3 but my updater is not showing the 16.04.4 update. Should i reinstall via pendrive or wait for the update to show up the update.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed all available updates with `apt` or the graphical software updater, you already have it. Minor versions (eg. 16.04.4) are just updates of the .iso image.